# ion-label component inside the stencil-component-starter not getting rendered

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

I cloned the `stencil-component-starter` from:

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter

Then on the file: `my-component.tsx` I have the following code:

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  @Prop() minHeartRate: number;
  @Prop() maxHeartRate: number;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Athlete: {this.first} {this.last} - Heart Rate Range:
        <ion-range mode="ios" dualKnobs={true} min={0} max={200} step={2} pin={true} snaps={true} value={{lower: this.minHeartRate, upper: this.maxHeartRate}}>
          <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
          <ion-label range-right>200</ion-label>
        </ion-range>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see here:

https://github.com/napolev/stencil-ion-range/blob/master/src/components/my-component/my-component.tsx

**[Before]** It was getting rendered **almost** properly with two issues `1 and 2`:
**[Now]** It is not getting rendered at all. So, there are three issues `1, 2 and 3`:

1. The `<ion-label/>` tags are ignored.
2. Each knob can move beyond of the other knob (please, ignore this, I think this is on purpose on new version).
3. This is a new issue that I just detected `(Current time: 2018-08-26 19:20)`. Like 12 hours ago (check timestamp on the repo) the repository: https://github.com/napolev/stencil-ion-range/ on commit `12c14b75cca92f19af6c5ccae60091319578cec7` was generating **almost** properly the `<ion-range/>` tag above, except issues 1 and 2 (check image below). But now after a clean install of this repository it doesn't render what you see on the image below anymore. This is weird. After doing that commit I checked that after a clean install it rendered that.

Here is what it was rendering before, that it is not getting rendered anymore:

[image]

**Reference:**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

**[EDIT 1]**

This is a response to the comment from Aaron Saunders below:

[ion-label component inside the stencil-component-starter not getting rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024158/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered#answer-52049046)

Aaron, I added the code you suggested as you can see here:

https://github.com/napolev/stencil-ion-range/commit/d3471825131d3d329901c73d8c6803a609b27c3b#diff-34c2a6c626ee2612cd4f12b2c004a0b1L16

but when running the code with: `$ npm start` the following is what is get rendered:

[image]

did you get the component rendered properly?

I removed the `node_modules` directory and installed them again with no success.

could you maybe try my repository?

as you can see, I have done just 2 commits on top of the official commits:

https://github.com/napolev/stencil-ion-range/commits/master

Just in case here are the versions I'm using for the primary tools:

```
$ node -v
v8.11.2

$ npm -v
6.1.0

$ ionic -v
ionic CLI 4.1.1
```

**[EDIT 2]**

There is a parallel discussion for this topic on:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered/139763

**[EDIT 3]**

This is a response to the comment from **Alexander Staroselsky** below:

[ion-label component inside the stencil-component-starter not getting rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024158/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered#answer-52087190)

Alexander, I tried your suggestion with the following changes:

https://github.com/napolev/stencil-ion-range/commit/68fce2abe25536b657f9493beb1cc56e26828e4f

Now the `<ion-range/>` component gets rendered (that's really good) but there is some problem on the rendering as you can see on the following image. The `<ion-label/>` components have a big width.

[image]

Any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks!

**[EDIT 4]**

Adding the suggestion from **Aaron Saunders** does the trick:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-range
        mode="ios"
        dualKnobs={true}
        min={0} max={200} step={2}
        pin={true} snaps={true}
        value={{ lower: this.minHeartRate, upper: this.maxHeartRate }}
    >
        <ion-label slot="start" style={{flex: 'none', margin: '0 30px 0 0'}}>0</ion-label>
        <ion-label slot="end" style={{flex: 'none', padding:' 0 0 0 30px'}}>200</ion-label>
    </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Thanks to **Alexander Staroselsky** and **Aaron Saunders** because by combining their suggestions I could get this work.

Comment: Do you either import '@ionic/core'; in your stencil-component-starter component or use include the CDN @ionic/core assets in your `index.html`? Creating a new stencil-component-starter project and importing/linking either is allowing the elements to be used and exported. There are definitely styling inconsistencies, but that is an entirely different issue related to the beta. I don't want to officially answer unless this obviously resolves the base issue of using @ionic/core components in the starter project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to either explicitly `import '@ionic/core';` in your [stencil-component-starter](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter) component or add [CDN scripts/styles](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter) to the `index.html`. I remember at one point either the toolkit or stencil-app-starter specifically had that import in a root element with an earlier version of @ionic/core beta or even an alpha.

Also, per [documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range), you would also need to wrap the `ion-range` with `ion-item` as well as using `slot="start"` and `slot="end"` instead of `range-left` and `range-right`.

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
import '@ionic/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  @Prop() minHeartRate: number;
  @Prop() maxHeartRate: number;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Athlete: {this.first} {this.last} - Heart Rate Range:
        <ion-item>
          <ion-range mode="ios" dualKnobs={true} min={0} max={200} step={2} pin={true} snaps={true} value={{lower: this.minHeartRate, upper: this.maxHeartRate}}>
            <ion-label slot="start">0</ion-label>
            <ion-label slot="end">200</ion-label>
          </ion-range>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will help ensure the styles are injected and the component renders properly. In all fairness, when I tried this, most of the styles came through, but there were definitely issues with the positioning of the slotted `ion-label` elements. There would definitely need to be some adjustments to the styling including flex grow/shrink/basis as well as positioning/margin of the end slot element. It is probably wise to submit the styling issues at @ionic/core github as well.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Alexander, I responded on **[EDIT 3]** on my original post. Thank you!

Comment: Alexander, when I take the way of importing: `@ionic/core` in my component everything works just fine, but the compiled component has lot of JavaScript files which I think lot of them is `@ionic/core` or `@stencil/core` source code. Imagine the case where I have 10 custom components, for each of them I'm gonna have maybe 10 times common code. I'm wondering if is there a way to prevent that?. Is maybe the second way you suggested above: "add CDN scripts/styles to the index.html" achieving this?, I mean, the previous core code is not incorporated on my code but I can use it via CDN?. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue? I'm importing `@ionic/core` in a new generated component with `npm init stencil` and trying to use `ion-label` or `ion-chip` but it still crashes: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Constructor for "ion-label#undefined" was not found`

Answer (score 1):

based on the latest 4.0 beta... I still do think there is a bug in the styling of the labels by default, but this is a work-around

reference to the doc since stencil uses ionic v4 - https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/range

```
<ion-range mode="ios" 
           dualKnobs={true} 
           min={0} max={200} 
           step={2} pin={true} 
           snaps={true} 
           value={{lower: 89, upper: 150}}>
   <ion-label slot="start" style={{flex: 'none',padding:'10px'}}>0</ion-label>
   <ion-label slot="end" style={{flex: 'none',padding:'10px'}}>200</ion-label>
</ion-range>
```

[image]

Comment: Aaron, still not working. For more details, I answered you on my original post on **[EDIT 1]**. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Finally I got this working by combining your suggestion with the suggestion from Alexander Staroselsky above.