# How to create a custom Stencil component with the Ionic PWA Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4, stenciljs

I just run the command:

```
$ npx create-stencil ionic-pwa
```

which created a vanilla `Ionic 4 PWA` with the following directory structure inside directory: `src`:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── icon
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       └── icon.png
├── components
│   ├── app-home
│   │   ├── app-home.css
│   │   ├── app-home.spec.ts
│   │   └── app-home.tsx
│   ├── app-profile
│   │   ├── app-profile.css
│   │   ├── app-profile.spec.ts
│   │   └── app-profile.tsx
│   └── my-app
│       ├── my-app.css
│       ├── my-app.spec.ts
│       └── my-app.tsx
├── components.d.ts
├── global
│   ├── app.css
│   └── app.ts
├── helpers
│   └── utils.ts
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
└── sw.js
```

Then I want to create a custom component with html tag: `comp-workspace` and file name: `comp-workspace.js` (or something similar) that I can insert on any vanilla `HTML`/`Javascript` page without using any Javascript framework.

There are some things to take into consideration here:

1. component: `comp-workspace` can include the following components: { `comp-gallery`, `comp-artboard`, `comp-text-editor`, `comp-layer-stack` }.
2. all above components can include standard `Ionic` components.

Please, take a look to the following diagram:

[image]

Here is the directory structure after adding my custom component: `comp-workspace` and its dependencies.

```
.
├── assets
│   └── icon
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       └── icon.png
├── components
│   ├── app-home
│   │   ├── app-home.css
│   │   ├── app-home.spec.ts
│   │   └── app-home.tsx
│   ├── app-profile
│   │   ├── app-profile.css
│   │   ├── app-profile.spec.ts
│   │   └── app-profile.tsx
│   ├── comp-workspace
│   │   ├── comp-workspace.css
│   │   ├── comp-workspace.spec.ts
│   │   └── comp-workspace.tsx
│   ├── comp-gallery
│   │   ├── comp-gallery.css
│   │   ├── comp-gallery.spec.ts
│   │   └── comp-gallery.tsx
│   ├── comp-artboard
│   │   ├── comp-artboard.css
│   │   ├── comp-artboard.spec.ts
│   │   └── comp-artboard.tsx
│   ├── comp-text-editor
│   │   ├── comp-text-editor.css
│   │   ├── comp-text-editor.spec.ts
│   │   └── comp-text-editor.tsx
│   ├── comp-layer-stack
│   │   ├── comp-layer-stack.css
│   │   ├── comp-layer-stack.spec.ts
│   │   └── comp-layer-stack.tsx
│   └── my-app
│       ├── my-app.css
│       ├── my-app.spec.ts
│       └── my-app.tsx
├── components.d.ts
├── global
│   ├── app.css
│   └── app.ts
├── helpers
│   └── utils.ts
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
└── sw.js
```

Then, I want to use my custom component in a way similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="https://my.repository.com/components/comp-workspace.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <comp-workspace attr1="..." attr2="..." attr3="..." ...></comp-workspace>
</body>

</html>
```

If I run the `build` command on the console I get the following output:

```
$ npm run build

> @ionic/pwa-toolkit@0.0.1 build D:\stencil-lab
> stencil build

[25:03.5]  @stencil/core v0.12.1
[25:03.9]  build, app, prod mode, started ...
[25:06.3]  transpile started ...
[25:12.3]  transpile finished in 6.02 s
[25:15.5]  module map started ...
[25:15.5]  generate styles started ...
[25:26.0]  compile global style start ...
[25:28.0]  compile global style finish in 2.03 s
[25:28.0]  generate styles finished in 12.50 s
[25:28.0]  module map finished in 12.50 s
[25:28.0]  generate bundles started ...
[25:28.2]  generate bundles finished in 237 ms
[25:28.2]  generate app files started ...
[25:29.6]  generate app files finished in 1.36 s
[26:03.4]  inject manifest into service worker started ...
[26:08.5]  inject manifest into service worker finished in 5.04 s

[ WARN  ]  build warn
           Generated an empty bundle

[26:08.5]  build finished in 64.58 s
```

I also get a new directory: `www` with the following content:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── icon
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       └── icon.png
├── build
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── 3hkybzk1.es5.js
│   │   ├── 3hkybzk1.js
│   │   ├── 3hkybzk1.sc.es5.js
│   │   ├── 3hkybzk1.sc.js
│   │   ├── 4jakisfl.es5.js
│   │   ├── 4jakisfl.js
│   │   ├── 4jakisfl.sc.es5.js
│   │   ├── 4jakisfl.sc.js
│   │   ├── aa33sq6q.es5.js
│   │   ├── aa33sq6q.js
│   │   ├── [... AND MANY MORE FILES]
│   │   └── svg
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       ├── ios-add-circle-outline.svg
│   │       ├── ios-add-circle.svg
│   │       ├── ios-add.svg
│   │       ├── ios-airplane.svg
│   │       ├── ios-alarm.svg
│   │       ├── ios-albums.svg
│   │       ├── ios-alert.svg
│   │       ├── ios-american-football.svg
│   │       ├── ios-analytics.svg
│   │       └── [... AND MANY MORE FILES]
│   ├── app.css
│   └── app.js
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── sw.js
└── workbox-v3.4.1
    ├── workbox-background-sync.dev.js
    ├── workbox-background-sync.dev.js.map
    ├── workbox-background-sync.prod.js
    ├── workbox-background-sync.prod.js.map
    ├── workbox-broadcast-cache-update.dev.js
    ├── workbox-broadcast-cache-update.dev.js.map
    ├── workbox-broadcast-cache-update.prod.js
    ├── workbox-broadcast-cache-update.prod.js.map
    ├── workbox-cache-expiration.dev.js
    ├── workbox-cache-expiration.dev.js.map
    └── [... AND MANY MORE FILES]

6 directories, 832 files
```

but as you can see, I don't get an actual javascript bundle file I can use to insert my custom component on any vanilla `HTML/Javascript` page.

**My question is:** how do I `build` just my custom component from inside this `Ionic 4 PWA` app?

Thanks!

**[EDIT 1]**

This is a response to the comment from **Alexander Staroselsky** below, where he says:

> You could consider using something like **stencil-component-starter** to
>   build individual web components that can be bundled and used
>   effectively anywhere.

That's a good point Alexander, and actually that was my initial idea but I found some problems which I posted on this forum:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered/139763/3#post_4

**Aaron Saunders** said there (as of `2018-08-28`):

> It appears that this project (**stencil-component-starter**) doesn't have `Ionic 4` in it by default.

Then he suggested me to use the `Ionic PWA Starter Kit` project and that's what I was trying to do here. Doing this way everything seems to work well (all `Ionic` components work), but now I just need to compile just my custom component to a separate file.

Here is a the same discussion in parallel in **StackOverflow**:

[ion-label component inside the stencil-component-starter not getting rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024158/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered)

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks Alexander. I responded you on **[EDIT 1]** on my original post, please, check.

Comment: Do you either `import '@ionic/core';` in your component or use include the [CDN](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/core#vanilla-html) @ionic/core assets in your project? Creating a new stencil-component-starter and importing/linking either is allowing the elements to be used and exported. There are definitely styling inconsistencies, but that is an entirely different issue related to the beta.

Comment: Alexander, could you maybe post that suggestion on the following post (StackOverflow) for the community convenience? I also can answer you there. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024158/ion-label-component-inside-the-stencil-component-starter-not-getting-rendered

Comment: Alexander, when I take the way of importing: `@ionic/core` in my component everything works just fine, but the compiled component has lot of JavaScript files which I think lot of them is `@ionic/core` or `@stencil/core` source code. Imagine the case where I have 10 custom components, for each of them I'm gonna have maybe 10 times common code. I'm wondering if is there a way to prevent that?. Is maybe the second way you suggested above: "add CDN scripts/styles to the index.html" achieving this?, I mean, the previous core code is not incorporated on my code but I can use it via CDN?. Thanks!